A necessary and sufficient condition for a compact operator
Let $X = \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ and $Q$ be the multiplication operator $(Qa)_j = q_ja_j$ with $(q_j)_j$ being a bounded sequence.
Give a $i)$ necessary and $ii)$ sufficient condition that $Q$ is compact.
From the course, I know that, if $(q_j)_j \in c_0(\mathbb{N})$ (where $c_0(\mathbb{N})$ contains all sequences converging to zero), then $Q$ is compact. Based on a theorem in our course, a sequence of compact operators $A_n: X \to Y$ converges to another compact operator $A: X \to Y$ if $Y$ is a Banach space. For $(q_j)_j \in c_0(\mathbb{N})$, we can see that the sequence $(Q_n)_n$ defined by
$$Q_j = q_j \ \ \text{for} \ \ j \leq n$$
$$Q_j = 0 \ \ \text{for} \ \ j > 0$$
has a finite-dimensional range. Hence, $(Q_n)_n$ is compact for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. And because $\lVert Q_n - Q \rVert = \text{sup}_{j \geq n}|q_j|$, we see that $Q_n \to Q$ which is why $Q$ is compact by the theorem above.
However, I don't know if that helps me at all to answer the question. Could anybody help me please?

Operator-norm limits of finite-rank (hence, compact) operators are compact?

You already showed that $(q_j) \in c_0$ is sufficient. In fact, it is also necessary. Indeed, if $(q_j) \not\in c_0$, then there is a $C > 0$ and a subsequence $(q_{j_i})$ s.t. $|q_{j_i}| > C$ for all $i$. But then $Qe_{j_i} = q_{j_i}e_{j_i}$ is a sequence in $Q(B_1(0))$ which admits no convergent subsequence, contradicting the assumption that $Q$ is compact.
